# What is the equation stands for in geometry(intuitively)?

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry, numeric, polynomial-math

I am writing a bilinear interpolation method.

This method can be abstract by solve the equation A*x = b, A is a 4x4 matrix below:

```
1 x1 y1 x1*y1
1 x2 y2 x2*y2 
1 x3 y3 x3*y3
1 x4 y4 x4*y4
```

Here, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) and (x4, y4) is four points containing the dst interpolation point.

My problem is when det(A) = 0(then x! = A-1*b), what is the quadrangle looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The determinant becomes 0 when one of the rows or columns can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. Using columns, this equation must hold for some constants a, b, c for each of the four points:

```
a*1 + b*x + c*y + xy = 0
```

This is the equation a [hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) with asymptotes parallel to the axis, so the determinant is zero if and only if the four points fall on the same hyperbola.

For example, if you pick the rectangle (-2, -1), (-1, -2), (1, 2), (2, 1) the determinant will be zero since the points fall on the hyperbola defined by t → (t, 2/t).

Another way to look at it: you are free to pick any 3 points. The three points define a unique hyperbola. The determinant is 0 if and only if you pick the fourth point from that hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

Joni's answer above is entirely correct, but here's a physical interpretation that you might like:

Picture a square as a well-behaved quadrilateral defined by the following four points: 1 = (0,0), 2 = (1,0), 3 = (1, 1), and 4 = (0, 1).

If you start skewing it by anchoring points 1 and 2 but tugging point 3 to the right in such a way that the sides remain the same length, but the angle between the x-axis and the line segment between points 2 and 3 changes from 90 degrees to 180 and the angle between the x-axis and the line segment between points 1 and 4 changes from 90 degrees to 0, the determinant will approach zero as the angle increases.  When you have points 1 = (0,0), 2 = (1, 0), 3 = (2,0), and 4 = (1,0) the quad will be collapsed to a line segment and the determinant will be zero.

You can run this experiment with your matrix and see if I'm correct.